# VSTS input dependent on other input

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In a VSTS task I have several inputs. I want to make on input dependent on another. Relevant parts of my JSON below:

```
 "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "Wakeup",
            "type": "boolean",
            "label": "Wakeup",
            "defaultValue": "false",
            "required": false,
            "helpMarkDown": "Makes a wake-up request to the site after deploying.",
            "groupName": "advanced"
        },
        {
            "name": "SiteUrl",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "SiteUrl",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": false,
            "helpMarkDown": "The url to the site.",
            "groupName": "advanced"
        }
    ]
```

If `Wakeup` is selected, then `SiteUrl` should be required. But if `Wakeup` isn't selected `SiteUrl` shouldn't even be editable for the user (if possible).

I've been looking at the [build task-schema](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/build-task-schema), but cannot figure it out. I guess I should be able to use `visibleRule`, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
{
      "name": "SiteUrl",
      "type": "string",
      "label": "SiteUrl",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "The url to the site.",
      "visibleRule": "Wakeup = true",
      "groupName": "advanced"
    }
```